# Visual Format Language width and height constraint not being respected

Tags: ios, visual-format-language

I have this view controller set up on a storyboard, and I need to add a MapView to it programmatically.

I want the map to fill the view's width and have a constant height of 100 on both orientations. Also, I want a spacing of 10 to the imageView that's below the map.

This is the code I'm using.

```
_map = [MyClass sharedMap]; // Get singleton
[_map removeFromSuperview]; // Remove from the other VC view
[_map removeConstraints:[_map constraints]]; // Remove constraints if any
[[self view] addSubview:_map];
[[self view] addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_map]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"_map" : _map}]];
[[self view] addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_map(100)]-10-[_sellerImage]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"_map" : _map, @"_imageView" : _imageView}]];
```

But the results are:

- the width is constant and not filling the screen width
- the height increases when it's on portrait orientation
- the 10 px spacing to the imageView is ok

Do I need to set a initial frame for the map?

This mapview is a singleton used in many views in order to save memory. This is its initialization code:

```
+ (MKMapView *)sharedMap {
  static MKMapView *mapView;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
    if (IS_IOS_7) {
      [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
      [mapView setPitchEnabled:NO];
    }
    [mapView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
  });

  return mapView;
}
```

Comment: Are there any layout warnings coming out in the console?

Comment: Can you include the code where you create the map view?

Comment: @jrturton, I get this errors when the orientation is portrait. On landscape, there are no errors: http://pastebin.com/wzH3qg4q Check the question update for the map creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this out early this morning.
When I initialize the map view, I shouldn't be setting an Autoresize Mask. Instead I should set:
`[mapView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];`

It is necessary to set a frame for the map view just once. I opted to set it during its initialization. After that, constraints and VFL take control of its position and dimensions.
All errors are gone and it works exactly as I wanted.

For the record, this is the full initialization method:

```
+ (MKMapView *)sharedMap {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
    [mapView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];

    // Configure the map view
    if (IS_IOS_7) {
      [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
      [mapView setPitchEnabled:NO];
    }
    [mapView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
  });

  return mapView;
}
```

Comment: You probably don't need to set the initial frame. It's the turning off autoresizing that is the key.

Comment: I thought I didn't, but then it'd crash saying `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:nan, nan span:nan, nan>'`

Comment: Must be a map view specific thing then, with auto layout you never normally set a frame.